# How to create "Start-up script" in AWS Sagemaker Studio

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

In AWS Sagemaker Studio, under `File > New > Notebook` There's a drop-down menu to select a kernel and **start-up script**:
[image]

How do you create and then use that startup script in the dropdown menu?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Studio startup script (i.e., lifecycle configuration) by following the AWS tutorial located [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/customize-amazon-sagemaker-studio-using-lifecycle-configurations/). Make sure your AWS CLI is updated to at least version `2.2.38` which [added this support](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/00ccf46cab877fbb4a29f2d31882d11137753158/CHANGELOG.rst#L192).

Lifecycle configurations have existed in SageMaker Notebooks for a while but were just recently added to SageMaker Studio (September 2021).